# asp.net 2000 Login Controls - Data in my own Sql server Database instead of a vs 2010 mdf file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm new to dot net. I have a sql 2008 database. Trying to create an application that has role based authentication. Want to use the login controls that comes with vs2010. When i tried using it, it creates its own db.

Is it possible to create these tables in my own db ie sql 2008 and map it to these login controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first install membership's database into own DB with aspnet_regsql.exe util.
Configure your membership provider in web.config and set up connection string to own DB.

More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx